# Show numbers on help lines (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to learn tikz, but since I can't visualize coordinates, I need to draw/show step numbers on help lines. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=red!40, dashed, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-9.9,-9.9) grid (9.9,9.9);
    \draw[<->,ultra thin] (-9,0)--(9,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,-9)--(0,9) node[above]{$y$};.
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like `\draw foreach\x in{1, ..., 9} { (\x, 1) node[above]{\x} };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like this:

[image]

then add only two extra lines in `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`.

```
\tkzInit[xmax=10,ymax=10,xmin=-10,ymin=-10]
%\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
```

Of course, use `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`.

Complete Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=10,ymax=10,xmin=-10,ymin=-10]
    %\tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[help lines, color=red!40, dashed, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-9.9,-9.9) grid (9.9,9.9);
    \draw[<->,ultra thin, step=1cm] (-9,0)--(9,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,-9)--(0,9) node[above]{$y$};.
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Update:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=10,ymax=10,xmin=-10,ymin=-10]
    %\tkzGrid
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[help lines, color=red!40, dashed, xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.5cm] (-9.9,-9.9) grid (9.9,9.9);
    \draw[<->,ultra thin, step=1cm] (-9,0)--(9,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[<->,ultra thin] (0,-9)--(0,9) node[above]{$y$};.
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is not compiling anymore. Can you help again?

Comment: @Mafsi It is working on my side. What problem are you facing? Let me know.

Comment: @Mafsi You can check your compiler please.

Comment: I get this `tikz-help-lines.tex:9: Undefined control sequence. l.9   \tkzAxeXY ? `

Comment: @Mafsi You can add `\usetkzobj{all}` to resolve the problem. Link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154348/tkz-euclide-error-undefined-control-sequence-tkzmarkangle

Comment: Not compiling... `Undefined control sequence. \usetkzobj{all}` even if I put the command before `begin{tikzpicture}` or in preamble